# Phonegap - ajax error with mobile data, only works on wifi

Tags: javascript, jquery, ajax, cordova

Shows me this error when the AJAX request with mobile data, any solution? only works on wifi. Address the jquery: [url](http://www.citram.es/HORARIOS/info.aspx?lineas=8_N_805___%2C8__441___%2C8__442___%2C8__448___%2C8__488___&estacion=8_08292)

[img error](https://i.stack.imgur.com/VfGmj.png)

Comment: Are you sure there isn't an ip address issue ?

Comment: ip address problem? not understand